# Cookie data is hidden in the request of the sampler in jmeter

Tags: performance, cookies, jmeter

My Application is passing cookie data information when checked through network inspection in application but however it is not seen in the request of the jmeter not even in the HTTP Header Manager not in Request when sampler is executed, I need to extract that cookie data information for processing the request however unable to do that

Here is the attached screenshot.

[Cookie Information-Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8fz5v.png)
[Cookie Data is blank- Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cHGtO.png)

Please let me know what solution should i have now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Make sure you add [HTTP Cookie Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) to your Test Plan
2. By default JMeter checks cookies integrity (i.e. whether all data is present, path matches current request path, etc), if the cookie, you're trying to use later on is not valid - JMeter will discard it. You can suppress cookie checking by adding the next line to *user.properties* file (lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation

   ```
   CookieManager.check.cookies=false
   ```

   JMeter restart will be required to pick the property up. See [HTTP Cookie Manager Advanced Usage - A Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/http-cookie-manager-advanced-usage-a-guide) for more information.

---

As a last resort you can always extract cookies from the previous response's [Set-Cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie) header using [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) and build your own cookies manually.